# Flex wrap css issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a HTML structure to show primary and secondary information in one row. Until now, the requirement was to show only 3 elements in a row which works perfectly fine.

but in a given scenario there are additional 3 elements  are coming from API which is shrinking the each element.

I want to wrap the next 3 elements in another row. The solution I tried with `flex-wrap` is not working.
(PS: can't simply amend the HTML structure as primary information is highlighted first & lazily the secondary info is shown. Please uncomment the code which shows in 1 row.)

```css
.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.primary-container {
  flex: 1 1 33.33333%;
  display: flex;
}


.card {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.secondary-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 66.66666%;
}

card.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
    <div class="primary-container">
        <div class="card">
          1
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="secondary-container">
       <div class="card">2</div>
       <div class="card">3</div>
       <!-- <div class="card break">4</div>
       <div class="card">5</div>
       <div class="card">6</div> -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What _reason_ would the elements have, to wrap into multiples lines - when you still allow them to _shrink_? Without specifying a width, at least a min-width, this simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Plus, you put `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the wrong element to begin with. This needs to go onto the flex _container_, in which you want to allow items to wrap into more than one line.

Comment: @CBroe - Primary container would only have 1 element,  secondary is the container where I want 2 elements and rest 3 to be in next line.

so secondary needs to wrap (that I thought of )

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using flex-wrap, but you need to adjust your CSS a bit.

```
.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow wrapping */
}

.primary-container {
  flex-basis: 33.33333%; /* Initially occupy 33.33% of the space */
}

.card {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Allow the card to grow, but not shrink */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding in the width calculation */
}

.secondary-container {
  flex-basis: 100%; /* Occupy full width initially */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow secondary cards to wrap */
}

.secondary-container .card {
  flex-basis: 33.33333%; /* Each card occupies 33.33% of the width */
}

/* Define breakpoints for smaller screens if needed */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .primary-container,
  .secondary-container .card {
    flex-basis: 50%; /* Two cards in a row for smaller screens */
  }
}

<div class="results">
  <div class="primary-container">
    <div class="card">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-container">
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card break">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

feel free to ask if you've questions.

Comment: want 
1 2 3  in one row , 4 5 6 in 2nd

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flex-wrap: wrap to both the .primary-container and .secondary-container

```
.primary-container {
  flex: 1 1 33.33333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.secondary-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 66.66666%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This should allow the child elements to wrap onto new lines when there is not enough space available in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is not always the solution. Float can do it here:

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  width:calc(100%/3); /* control the width you want */
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* the below is only needed if you will use a small width */
.break {
  clear: both;
}

.results {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
  <div class="primary-container">
    <div class="card">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-container">
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card break">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```